# Is this an oxymoron or do they juxtapose each-other?

Tags: phrases, oxymoron

I am currently reading the book 'Spies' by Michael Frayn, and this phrase comes up quite often:

> 'Everything is as it was; and everything has changed'

The use of the semi-colon between the two clauses I assumed suggested that the latter statement explains the first (as that is the use of the semi-colon in this way). If that is the case, then surely they contradict eachother.

My question is that as this is the case, are the two statements oxymoronic or juxtaposing?

Comment: Looks like a typo. ...is *as* it was... (not "at it was").  The semicolon simply identifies the two statements as separate independent clauses but semantically a unit.  What establishes juxtaposition here is the parallelism of the syntax.

Comment: Like "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times ..." from A Tale of Two Cities, this is a contradiction that is trying to say something 'profound'.

Comment: I am trying to use this in an essay to explain someone's childish innocence. What was the point that TRomano was making? Yes it does look like a typo, but that is exactly the wording of the text..which I guess suggests that. So is it a juxtaposition of the syntax in the typo?

Comment: @Desthstro It looks like TRomano was focusing on the syntax. I was looking at the semantics. If we assume "at" was a typo, do our comments together answer your question? (You can also ping to ask TRomano directly by using the "@" convention as I did with your username.)

Comment: @Lawrence I understand that he was focusing on the syntax. My problem is that because I am trying to use this statement in the actual essay to explain someone's childish innocence, linking to his 'memory lane', I am trying to understand whether it is a contradiction and wwhat it is for so I can explain the quote. Is it a juxtaposition to make something profound? as it is a contradiction and what is it about the syntax. (authors make things so confusing!)

Comment: @TRomano it was actually a typo on my part! The quote is 'everything is as it was; and everything has changed'

Comment: If you don't understand it, then don't use in an essay!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because interpretation and analysis of English literature is off-topic.

Comment: @TrevorD but I can see several questions that ask things like 'Is X an oxymoron'. I am asking exactly the same thing, just whether it is a juxtaposition or an oxymoron

Comment: »The use of the semi-colon between the two clauses I assumed suggested that the latter statement explains the first (as that is the use of the semi-colon in this way)« — No, that's a _colon_, not a semi-colon. A semi-colon just lets you know that the two clauses are more closely related than if they'd been separated by a full stop, but less than if by a comma.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thanks so much, I would have got that wrong! If that is the case, have I interpreted it incorrectly or is it a juxtaposition (or oxymoron)?

Comment: Well, juxtaposition is just placing two things next to each other to compare or contrast them, so it definitely is that. Whether it's an oxymoron too is more debatable. I'd say probably no.

Comment: @Desthstro In reply to [your question to me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338844/is-this-an-oxymoron-or-do-they-juxtapose-each-other?noredirect=1#comment779858_338844), I don't have any more of substance to add beyond my [original comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338844/is-this-an-oxymoron-or-do-they-juxtapose-each-other?noredirect=1#comment779853_338844). Your *memory lane* comment strengthens the notion that although everything remained the same, it didn't *feel* the same to the older person.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet so if the semi-colon just shows that it is profound, is the juxtaposition being deliberately used to add emphasis?

Comment: @Lawrence that is exactly what I think the comment is trying to show...I think atleast. The juxtaposition of the two I guess just emphasises this point

Comment: Some would claim that it's an oxymoron.  But it's also a well-established literary device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb "juxtapose" requires contrasting things placed next to one other: 
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/juxtapose

Oxymoron Definition :
Oxymoron is a figure of speech in which two opposite ideas are joined to create an effect.
The common oxymoron phrase is a combination of an adjective proceeded by a noun with contrasting meanings, e.g. “cruel kindness” or “living death”. 
However, the contrasting words/phrases are not always glued together.
The contrasting ideas may be spaced out in a sentence, e.g. “In order to lead, you must walk behind.”

http://literarydevices.net/oxymoron :
In the light of above, you may please see that your sentence  is an Oxymoron  juxtaposed.
Hope I am clear enough.